# File path saved to CoreData but NSData works only on first call

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, core-data, nsdata

I'm downloading a picture from internet and storing its data locally then saving the path in my CoreData, this way:

```
       getDataFromUrl(url!) { (data, response, error)  in
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) { () -> Void in
                guard let data = data where error == nil else { return }
                print(response?.suggestedFilename ?? "")
                print("Download Finished")
                    let filename = self.getDocumentsDirectory().stringByAppendingPathComponent(userKey as! String + ".png")
                    data.writeToFile(filename, atomically: true)
                    user.setValue(filename, forKey: "avatar")
                    do {
                        try managedContext.save()
                    }
                    catch let error as NSError  {
                        print("Could not save \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
                    }
                }
            }
```

The save does seem to work (I debugged by printing the data received and the data inside the file once copied and I don't have any `managedContext` error).

On the next view, I do use a `UITableView` and on `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

```
    let path = authorArray.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row).objectAtIndex(0).objectForKey("avatar")! as! String
    let name = authorArray.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row).objectAtIndex(0).objectForKey("name")
    do {
        let data = try NSData(contentsOfFile: path, options: NSDataReadingOptions())
        let image = UIImage(data: data)
        cell.profilePicture.image = image
        cell.profilePicture.layer.cornerRadius = cell.profilePicture.layer.cornerRadius / 2;
        cell.profilePicture.layer.masksToBounds = true;
    }
    catch {
        print("failed pictures")
    }
```

The thing is I get the photo on my `cell.profilePicture` but as soon as I do any modification elsewhere and relaunch my application from xCode, I get the error message. The pictures path did not change but the datas obtained from it are `nil`. I can't find a reason why it does work until I update the code. Any solutions to make it work everytime ?

Comment: The Documents directory can change - particularly between builds.  You should not store the full path, only the last part - the filename and extension - in CoreData.  After fetching, lookup the application documents directory and append the filename to the doc directory path.

Answer (score 1):

As pbasdf stated on comments, I was storing the whole Document directory path instead of just the filename + extension. Documents directory changes on every build.